# Export notebook to HTML produces low resolution GIF

Tags: export, html

I have equations written in my notebooks as text (the cells set as Format -> Style -> Text).
When exporting the notebook to HTML (File -> Save As.. -> HTML) with the GIF option (the default) an HTML file is produced along with folders: HTMLFiles and HTMLLinks. The HTMLFiles folder contains GIF images of the equations in the text, but they are very low resolution / quality. Is there a way to make Export set them to a higher resolution?

motivation: to write equations in Mathematica (it is nice to write in) and output the equations as images to use in a presentation.

I have tried: 
SetOptions[Image, ImageSize -> 5000];
SetOptions[Image, ImageResolution -> 5000];
SetOptions[Graphics, ImageSize -> 5000];
SetOptions[Rasterize, RasterSize -> 1000];

With no luck.

Thanks,

Comment: Does changing menu setting **File** > **Printing Settings** > **Printing Environment** to **Working** help?

Answer (score 4):

Ok well I found an obvious way to do it.. simply make the font bigger. The exported image scales up with the font size. 
Can Edit Stylesheet.. to change the size of the body font for the whole workbook.

Comment: I have found that using Magnification to enlarge the size of the target image or object before exporting it is a good trick to augment the resolution of exported images.